# For a stochastic row matrix $A$, invertibility of $I-A$

Tags: markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

Consider a Markov process $X_t$ where $t$ belongs to natural numbers, which takes values on a finite state space $\mathcal{X}$. We say that $x \in \mathcal{X}$ is an absorbing state if $X_t = x$ implies $X_{\tau} = x$ for all $\tau \ge t$. We say a state is non-absorbing if it is not an absorbing state.

Suppose that $n$ states of the given Markov chain are non-absorbing and $s$ states are absorbing. Then we can partition the state transition matrix as
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 0 & I_s
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $I_s$ is the $s \times s$ identity matrix.

How does one prove that $$I_n - A$$ is invertible, where, $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix?

Source of my question: Definition 8.17 and Theorem 8.9 on page 83, and the first paragraph on page 84 of [these notes](https://www.iith.ac.in/%7Em_vidyasagar/RL/Gen/RL-Notes.pdf).

Comment: $(I_n-A)\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 0$ so it is not invertbile.  Check the definition of row stochastic-- it tells you $A\mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$.

Comment: Take $A$ to be $A_{ij} = 1-\delta_{ij}$. Then $A$ satisfies your definition but $(I-A)_{ij} = 1$ for all $i,j$

Comment: @guidoar that matrix is not stochastic (unless $n=2$).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe you, but it *does* satisfy the claimed definition for non-absorbing stochastic matrix given in the post, no? Each row is of the form $(1,\ldots, 1,\overbrace{0}^i,1,\ldots,1)$ which is not equal to the $i$-th row of $I_n$ (also, I should have defined $A$ to be $A_ij = \delta_ij -1$, can't edit the typo)

Comment: What's in the post is the definition of non-absorbing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ah, okay, my bad. I thought this was the definition for "non-absorbing stochastic row matrix". Maybe I'm being annoying but I would rather say "Define a stochastic row matrix to be non-absorbing if..."

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I had hastily put up a short version of my true question, and made mistakes. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: The idea for the corrected problem is the same as in the first comment. $0=(I-A)v=v-Av$ is equivalent to $Av=v$, so ....

Comment: @GerryMyerson so are you saying that $I_n - A$ is not invertible? And what is exactly the $v$ here? Because the one vector won't satisfy $A\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I maybe got that wrong. But consider the case where there are no absorbing states. Then if $v$ is any steady-state vector for $A$, $vA=v$, we have $v(I-A)=0$, so I get that $I-A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Yes, understood. But could you give any input on how would we tackle the case with absorbing states, as in the current question?

Comment: See theorem 2.16 in James Kirkwood, *Markov Processes*. First we show that $A^k \to 0$, then it follows that $x  = A x = A^k x$ implies $x = 0$.